# upload files with ionic file transfer

Tags: ionic-framework, file-transfer

Hello I would like to know if someone can help me, I want to upload files to my server on localhost with ionic using filetransfer, I have no idea how to do it. Can somebody help me? Thanks.
In the preferred Pdfs, but it can be any type of files

Answer (score 0):

First you need to select a file (an image from your gallery, or a pdf as you say). Then having the path to that file:

```
const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

const options: FileUploadOptions = {
    fileKey: 'file',
    fileName: 'uploadfile',     // Name received in the server,
    mimeType: 'image/jpeg',     // or application/pdf for pdf
    headers: {...}              // (Optional) if needed
};

fileTransfer.upload( filename, url, options ).then( response => {
    // Response here
}).catch(err => {
    // Error here
});
```

Filename is the path to the file in your device (the selected pdf file) and url is the url to your server where you are uploading.

Comment: thanks for reply, I have uninstalled the plugin because it is already obsolete